# Automatically unindent "end" in ruby-mode after typing it?

Tags: ruby, emacs, ruby-mode

Is it possible to set `ruby-mode` to *automatically* unindented the end?

For instance, after the end is typed as so:

```
def foo
  # indented
  end
```

It should turn into this:

```
def foo
  # indented
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your .emacs to enable ruby electric mode by adding the following:

```
(require 'ruby-electric)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook (lambda () (ruby-electric-mode t)))
```

This will add a correctly indented end whenever you type class or def.

Comment: @Tass did you ever get a chance to try this?  If you found a better solution follow up on your original post if you don't mind.